# Как изменить перемещение каретки в vim?

Tags: vim, vi

В привычных мне редакторах при нажатии стрелки вниз каретка переходит на следующую(в окне приложения) строку, пытаясь при этом отсчитать от начала строки такое же количество символов. (x,y)->(x,y+1). В Vim перенос происходит в начало реально новой строки. Как это изменить?

Comment: Это происходит если `y+1` - пустая строка или всегда?

Comment: всегда. То есть, допустим, у меня в окне текст отображается так(* - место каретки):
1 абвг
2 деё*ж
зийк
3 лмно
Я ожидаю, что после нажатия стрелки вниз каретка перейдёт к символу "к"(на экране это третья строчка). А в Vim идёт переход к "л"(действительно третья строчка).

Comment: для проверки запустите программу без чтения vimrc и загрузки плагинов: `$ vim -u NONE` // комментарии не подходят для форматированного текста. лучше дополните вашим примером текст вопроса.